# Not able to generate video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, phantomjs

I need to generate a vedio from a web page by capturing the screen. I tried in several ways but not able to find the solution. Any help can be appreciated. I am using phantomJS and FFmpeg

Thanks
Jaya

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on that site: 
http://www.linuceum.com/Desktop/recordFFmpeg.php
Hope that helps you get started

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s <Screen Resolution> -r <Frame Rate> -i :0.0 -qscale <Quality 1-5> <Output Filename>
```